# How to test that my Ultralight 2.0 IOT agent receives payload

Tags: fiware

I am using the Ultralight 2.0 IOT Agent.
Although I can see that the payload, that my gateway sends, is subscribed at a specific topic into the mosquitto MQTT broker, how could I test that the IOTAgent is listening at port 4061 and that it is receiving something from the broker?

I am refering to the IOTAgent-UL which is running on a CentOS 7 VM as a service. I have access to it with REST calls and I also see that the payloads, that my gateway sends, are subscribed into the MQTT broker. How could I pass my payloads from the mosquitto to the IOTAgent and after to the Context Broker?

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for seems to be related with the basic operational workflow of the IOTAgents in general. Thus, I'd recommend you to have a look to the following [Step by step guide](https://github.com/telefonicaid/iotagent-json/blob/master/docs/stepbystep.md). It is based in another agent (the one for JSON payloads instead of UL) but most of the procedure is the same, so I think it could be useful.

**EDIT:** JSON format is documented [here](https://github.com/telefonicaid/iotagent-json/blob/master/docs/usermanual.md#apioverview). UL format is documented [here](https://github.com/telefonicaid/iotagent-ul/blob/master/docs/usermanual.md#apioverview). Payload format is indepedent of the transport, i.e. is the same no matter if you use HTTP or MQTT.

Comment: What i would like to ask is what format of payload should be published to the mqtt broker in order to be readable for my json/mqtt iot agent; For example if it is encrypted i could not create ngsi entities with encrypted attributes.So should i do the decryption of the payload before i publish it to the mqtt broker?

Comment: Answer has been edited to include information about JSON and UL formats.